# Is it okay to use mongoose's mpromise even if it's deprecated?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am getting the following error when using mongoose with my `Node` application.

```
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

I got many solutions for this from SO and some other sites as well. All says to plug-in some other promise library like native, bluebird etc.

But I could not find anywhere what problem it may cause using `mpromise`, apart from displaying that warning. Is it okay to ignore the warning and continue using `mpromise`? Or Should I have to change the promise library? Till now I did not face any problem using that. That's why I am confused about changing the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use `mpromise` for now. `Mongoose` is going to stop `mpromise` support. `Mongoose`'s latest version is `4.9.0`. From `5.0` onwards, it will not support `mpromise`, and will take native promise library as default. From mongoose docs,

> DEPRECATED. Mongoose 5.0 will use native promises by default (or
>   bluebird, if native promises are not present) but still support
>   plugging in your own ES6-compatible promises library. Mongoose 5.0
>   will not support mpromise.

See [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#ES6Promise-js)